# Dynamically get URL for JQuery Ajax request from Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I have a JQuery Autocomplete function that I need to be able to pass a url into. I'm trying to pull the url from the html data-url attribute, however I'm currently getting a variable is undefined message in the JavaScript console, so I know I'm not getting the values I expect. I've included my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JQuery Function:

```
 $(function () {
    $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var baseURL = $(this).data("url");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: baseURL + request.term,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data)
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
    });
```

HTML Element:

```
<td style="width: 90%">
   <label for="tag_Name" class="inline">Server Tags: </label>
      <input class="fixed autocomplete" type="text" id="tag_Name" placeholder="Type tags to add..." data-url="/RequestFieldValues/GetLikeResourceTags/?prefix=" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
$(function () {
    $(".autocomplete").each(function() {
        var baseURL = $(this).data("url");
        $(this).autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: baseURL + request.term,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data)
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1,
        });
    });
});
```

I've put the `.autocomplete()` inside an `each()` function so you can refer to `this` to get the base url from the data attribute.  You can then pass that into the `source` function.

Incidentally, if there is more than 1 input then you need to make each one have a unique ID.  You shouldn't have elements with the same ID :)

Comment: Still coming up undefined even with quotes.

Comment: Try that and let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to change the URL in a ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://static.url/",
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    this.url = "http://dyn.url/" + "here"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you should be doing is :

```
 $(function () {
var baseURL = $(".autocomplete").data('url');
    $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: baseURL + request.term,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data)
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
    });
```

Comment: there are more than one element with the ".autocomplete" class so that I dont think will work either. I need to get the URL from the .autocomplete class making the request which is why I was attempting to use the $(this) reference